# load file xml on view folder codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, xml, codeigniter

I make data.php in view folder like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js"></script>
    <div id="flashPlayer">
      This text will be replaced by the flash music player.
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("playerMultipleList.swf", "mymovie", "295", "200", "7", "#FFFFFF"); 
   so.addVariable("autoPlay","yes")
   so.addVariable("repeat","false")
   so.addVariable("playlistPath","playlist.xml")
   so.write("flashPlayer");
</script>`
```

and my trouble is, I put file swfobject.js, playerMultipleList.swf, playlist.xml on view folder too and when I run, system can't read all of that file.

have any solution ???

Answer (score 0):

When you link file source like you did in your view it doesn't look for the files in view folder but root of your system. so you can create a folder at the root of your system(where application, system folders are, or basicaly where index.php is) and put your files there. then you can ink like in the below code. I assumed the folder name is "inc".

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="inc/swfobject.js"></script>
 <div id="flashPlayer">
  This text will be replaced by the flash music player.
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
   var so = new SWFObject("inc/playerMultipleList.swf", "mymovie", "295", "200", "7", "#FFFFFF"); 
   so.addVariable("autoPlay","yes")
   so.addVariable("repeat","false")
   so.addVariable("playlistPath","playlist.xml")
   so.write("flashPlayer");
</script>
```